# tornado + python. wait for chained operations to finish with callbacks

Tags: python, asynchronous, callback, tornado

I have a simple handler like so :

```
@asynchronous
@gen.engine
def post(self):
    result = functionOne()
    foo = MyObject()
    bar = AnotherObject()
```

But I'd like for result to come back, then execute foo, then bar in a sequence. I've tried using nested callbacks as per http://www.tornadoweb.org/documentation/gen.html but without much luck.

thx!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are using the gen.engine, but you need to make your method calls into `yield` with a `gen.Task` calls.

Example from a project of mine:

```
customer = yield gen.Task( self.paymentService.charge, email, cardUri )
sub = yield gen.Task( self.paymentService.schedule, customer )
```

The above will first do the `charge` part then return the result and then call the `schedule` and return the `subscription` object from that call.

The methods that you call with the `gen.Task` need to look like the following:

```
def customer( self, email, cardUri, callback=None ):
```

Where `callback` will be the function to call to actually return the value from the `gen.Task`.

I have it setup to work with or without the callback so I can more easily test my methods. Which is just a simple test if `callback` is `None` or not and if it isn't `None` then it gets called else it returns normally.

[gen.Engine Docs](http://www.tornadoweb.org/documentation/gen.html)

EDIT:

Ok, to clarify the above it a complete function that works with `gen.Tasks` looks like the following.

```
def delete_customer( customer_id, callback ):
    result = customerService.delete( customer_id )

    callback( result )
```

The above when used in a `gen.Task` will look like the following.

```
@gen.engine
def perform_customer_delete( customer_id )
    result = yield gen.Task( delete_customer, customer_id )
    return result
```

This means to call the `delete_customer` with the parameter `customer_id` and then I want the result of this function, the return, to be given to `result`. So, when the `delete_customer` function completes and sends the `result` of the `self.customerService.delete` to the `callback` the `gen.Task` will then return the value and store it in `result`.

Now, you can use the `result` however you wish, in my example it is returned.

For you example it looks like you want to do the following.

```
@asynchronous
@gen.engine
def post(self):
    result = yield gen.Task( functionOne )
    foo = yield gen.Task( MyObject )
    bar = yield gen.Task( AnotherObject )
```

This will first call the `functionOne` then go to the next `gen.Task` and execute the `MyObject` and so forth. But, you must follow the pattern where you have a `callback` parameter in your methods in order to use `gen.Task` correctly otherwise you cannot get the result back.

This is where my second, confusing example, comes into play.

In order to get around this requirement and to allow my code to work with `gen.Task` and without I do the following.

```
def delete_customer( customer_id, callback=None ):
    result = customerService.delete_customer( customer_id )
    if callback:
        callback( result )
    return result
```

This allows me to use the code in a lot more situations without breakage.

Comment: I've looked at your example and find it quite confusing. Why is the `customer` result named the same as the method you give as an example ? Also, what would `self.paymentService.charge` look like/return? You mention `subscription` being returned, but I see no reference to it? I looked at the docs, and they are rather hard to understand too. None of their examples actually run in their posted form. Thanks!

Comment: Ok the first example is not tied to the method definition, sorry for the confusion there. I will write up an explanation what is expected as the return.

Comment: Great! Much clearer now, in combination with [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8812715/using-a-simple-python-generator-as-a-co-routine-in-a-tornado-async-handler), makes sense. One more thing - let's suppose `customerService.delete` was a method that also contained a gen.task (nested), I assume the same logic would need to be followed, otherwise the second nested gen.task might finish before its parent is returned?

Comment: A way to insure that the method's go in order is to use a `gen.Callback` and a `gen.Wait`. [gen.engine docs](http://www.tornadoweb.org/documentation/gen.html)