# Using python generators at the same time as Tornado

Tags: python, generator, tornado, yield

I have a tornado server which I am ok with running synchronously. One of the callback handlers calls a method in another module which internally uses generators to iterate over results, using the yield keyword.

Calling the function directly works however triggering it from the tornado server seems to stop execution as soon as it reaches the yield keyword.

Is it possible to use both? This is in a way the opposite question to [Using a simple python generator as a co-routine in a Tornado async handler?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8812715/using-a-simple-python-generator-as-a-co-routine-in-a-tornado-async-handler)

Calling code from the tornado end e.g.:

```
class SearchHandler(tornado.web.RequestHandler):
    # @tornado.web.asynchronous
    # @gen.coroutine
    def get(self): 
        self.write(ice.getStructs(collapseArguments(self.request.arguments)))
```

I don't mind it running asynchronously, but don't need to convert the whole function to be a generator

Comment: Can you share the calling code?

Comment: So, ice.getStructs is returning a generator?

Comment: It's returning a string value. During the course of making the string, a generator is used to iterate over some pymongo results. It seems to stop at the yield inside that.

Comment: Hmm, That's strange. Here's an example program where a GET handler calls into a function that uses yield internally, and it works just fine for me: https://gist.github.com/dano/19668618c513a33ccce6. Using yield inside a function that isn't decorated with something from `tornado.gen` should just act like normal Python; Tornado has no control over it. Where can I find the ice libary? Google isn't turning anything up.

Comment: You're totally right, it should and it does. Upon further inspection, the error was somewhere else related to arguments passing through tornado, I jumped to the wrong conclusion - thanks for confirming that of course yield inside non-decorated functions should act normally.